# Access a different object's properties inside another object

Tags: javascript

I have a dummy api response consisting of a results array which has objects in it. When I try  to map over this array and try to access each individual's object's properties inside another object I'm creating, it throws an error. Any idea what could be wrong?

here's a code snippet

```
import { result } from "./partnership_rewards_response.json";

result.map((partner,index)=>{
    const obj = {
        partner.name,
        partner.class
    }
})
```

and this is how my json file looks like

```
{
"result":[obj1, obj2, ...]
}
```

and the error I'm getting is `Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","`

EDIT:
I forgot to specify, I'm trying to populate content in react using useState. so object structure is already initialized in the default value

EDIT2: here's How I'm trying to populate it

```
const [showModal, setModal] = useState(false);
const [modalContent, setModalContent] = useState({
    partner_name: "",
    coupon_image:"",
    coupon_code : "",
    coupon_content:"",
    terms:"",
    redemption_steps:"",
});

setModalContent(
{
partner.partner_logo,
partner.coupon_image
}
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're trying to use shorthand property notation in your object literal, but you can only do that when the source of the property value is a simple identifier like `example`, not a property expression like `person.name`. When the source of the value isn't just a simple identifier, you have to use the "old" (pre-ES2015) full property syntax (`name: value`) instead.

You need to give the property name explicitly:

```
result.map((partner,index)=>{
    const obj = {
        name: partner.name,
        class: partner.class,
    };
    // ...I assume there's more here...
})
```

or re your edit (confusing that you've changed property names):

```
setModalContent({
    partner_logo: partner.partner_logo,
    image: partner.image,
});
```

You could also do it with destructuring and property shorthand notation:

```
result.map(({name, class},index)=>{
    const obj = {
        name,
        class,
    };
    // ...I assume there's more here...
})
```

or re your edit, if you've destructured `person`, you could do:

```
setModalContent({
    partner_logo,
    image,
});
```

Comment: please see the edit, I am trying to populate content using this, do I still need to specify the property names?

Comment: @Altair21 - I'm afraid I don't understand the edit; code might make it clearer. Fundamentally, it doesn't matter what you're *doing* with the object, you need to create it with valid syntax. `{ person.name, person.class }` isn't a valid object initializer, but `{ name: person.name, class: person.class }` and `{ name, class }` (if you use the destructuring solution) are.

Comment: @Altair21 - Re the updated edit -- yes, the same thing applies. I've updated the answer.

Comment: can you explain why it wont work without destructuring? thanks

Comment: @Altair21 - I did that in the first sentence of the answer, but perhaps not clearly enough; I've expanded on that first paragraph.

Comment: Thanks for the info. this explains quite a bit of things for me

Answer (score 1):

Shorthand objects syntax doesn't work because you have dots in the key names.

You can change it to something like:

```
import { result } from "./partnership_rewards_response.json";

result.map((partner,index)=>{
    const obj = {
        partnerName: partner.name,
        partnerClass: partner.class
    }
})
```

Comment: please see the edit, I am trying to populate content using this, do I still need to specify the property names?

Comment: Can you show code that defines the object structure?

Comment: Please see the edit

Comment: Then initialize your object like `{ partner_name: partner.name, etc`. But I don't see partner_class here.

Comment: that was just an example, I didnt follow the exact names for the properties but I'll do this thanks

Answer (score 1):

your shorthand syntax is wrong change your code to this

```
result.map((partner,index) => {
 const obj = {
     name : partner.name,
     class : partner.class
  }
})
```

This should work